# incorporating scrolling feed twitter style

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to make a twitter like system that scrolls through info slowly and then repeats.
I have it down(kinda) thanks to this [tutorial](http://www.9lessons.info/2009/02/auto-scrolling-effect-with-javascript.html). I have it working on its own and I added my own content but when I try adding it to my webpage it takes a c*** on me and throws all of my content all together at the top of the page. Any suggestions?

```
<div class="header">
    <h2><span>Resteruant Consulting</span></h2>
    <h1>Tasty Solutions</h1>
</div>

<div class="content">
                    <DIV align=center style="background:#fff">
                    <DIV id="tempholder"></DIV>


                    <SCRIPT language=JavaScript 
                    src="dhtmllib.js"></SCRIPT>

                    <SCRIPT language=JavaScript 
                    src="scroller.js"></SCRIPT>

                    <SCRIPT language=JavaScript 
                    src="mydata.js"></SCRIPT>

                    <SCRIPT language=JavaScript>
  //SET SCROLLER APPEARANCE AND MESSAGES
  function runmikescroll() {

  var layer;
  var mikex, mikey;

  // Locate placeholder layer so we can use it to position the scrollers.

  layer = getLayer("placeholder");
  mikex = getPageLeft(layer);
  mikey = getPageTop(layer);

 // Create the first scroller and position it.

 myScroller1.create();
 myScroller1.hide();
 myScroller1.moveTo(mikex, mikey);
 myScroller1.setzIndex(200);
 myScroller1.show();
 }

 window.onload=runmikescroll
                    </SCRIPT>

 <center><DIV id='placeholder'></DIV></div></DIV></center> 
    </div>
```

I have all the other javascript in the same directory. I have javascript enabled in my web browser, and it works on its on its just when I incorporate it into my index.html it gets screwy.

[image: Here's what it looks like.]

Comment: Dude, we're not going to study a whole tutorial for you. Give us some more specific info.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

each headline has a "position:absolute", perhaps if you put those headlines in a div with

```
position:relative;
```

so the headlines at least will stay just in that div.

if I'm wrong pardon me, if I'm right let me know.